# Using elements that are added to an array with (document.getElementById('ID'))

Tags: javascript

Why does this code not work?

```
var all_obj_element= new Array();
all_obj_element[0]= document.getElementById('Img3');            
alert(all_obj_element[0].style.width);
```

The alert shows an empty box!

Comment: Did you try .width instead of style.width ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you haven't set the width. Here is how you get the computed style value of an element:

```
var computedStyle = function (el,style) {
    var cs;
    if (typeof el.currentStyle != 'undefined'){
        cs = el.currentStyle;
    }
    else {
        cs = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null);
    }
    return  cs[style];
}
```

Now let's get the value:

```
var element = document.getElementById('Img3');

alert(computedStyle(element,'width'));
```

Comment: @hamze the computed style is the value  computed when the stylesheet or in line style are processed

Answer (score 2):

The element with the id `Img3` has not had its `.style.width` property set (which can be done by assigning a value to it via JavaScript, or by using the `style` attribute).

Quirks Mode has an article on [how to read the computed style in a cross-browser fashion](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html).

Answer (score 0):

If there is no need to see the STYLEd width, just look at the width:

```
var all_obj_element= [];
all_obj_element[0]= document.getElementById('Img3');            
alert(all_obj_element[0].width);
```