# Errors with changing a header's color

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I have a webpage I am designing with html, css, and JS. I have them properly hooked up, but for some reason my header will not do what I want. I have tried everything, does anyone know where I went wrong?

I want it so that when I mouse over the header or click the header, the color will change. This does not happen.

The important code in a JS-Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DITTO/c37zxdke/

```
//javascript
var col = document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color;

function orangeToBlue() {
    col = "#197CFF";
}
function blueToGreen() {
    col = "#19FF29";
}
function greenToPink() {
    col = "#FF19EF";
}
function pinkToOrange() {
    col = "#FF9C19";
}



function changeColor() {
    if (document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color === "#FF9C19") {
        orangeToBlue();
} else if (document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color === "#197CFF") {
        blueToGreen();
    } else if (document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color === "#19FF29") {
        greenToPink();
    } else if(document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color === "#FF19EF") {
        pinkToOrange();
    }
}


//html
<h1 id="webTitle" onmouseover="changeColor()">Webpage Title</h1>


//css
#webTitle:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#webTitle {
    text-shadow: 3.5px 3.5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: fantasy;
    color: #FF9C19;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fiddle I posted most recently under g4u's answer works, fiddle doesn't work. FIDDLE IS BROKEN! Try it in a notepad and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to get what 
`document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color` output?

When I log this action it's give me a blank string, can you confirm?

If you have the same blank string, then look at this this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688638/document-getelementbyid-style-display-is-blank) the answer looks really good, and has nice links.

Or you can just look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9444783/4933917) (from a duplicate).

Hope it's gonna help you a bit.

And the answer of Eduardo Escobar is important too.

Comment: I did look at his answer and modified my code. same thing happened. Also, I knew about the blank string. But when I looked up the documentation for style on the JS DOM, it said that the code was right. I'm confused. Ill check the other post. Didn't notice that it existed, thanks for the link.

Comment: And try with putting the JS before the html, like here http://jsfiddle.net/c37zxdke/8/

Answer (score 0):

Your functions orangeToBlue(), blueToGreen(), greenToPink() and pinkToOrange() aren't making any effect, although they are being called, they're just defining a variable, nothing else.

Comment: The variables were a test to try some other things, this is the updated fiddle with my original code: https://jsfiddle.net/DITTO/c37zxdke/

Answer (score 0):

You should use rgb(rrr,ggg,bbb) color values in javaScript at theplace of using #rrggbb color values and CSS for seting initial color for your text.

```
//javascript

        document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color = "#197CFF";
        function orangeToBlue() {
            document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color = "#197CFF";
        }

        function blueToGreen() {
            document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color = "#19FF29";
        }

        function greenToPink() {
            document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color = "#FF19EF";
        }

        function pinkToOrange() {
            document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color = "#FF9C19";
        }



        function changeColor() {
            if (document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color === "rgb(255, 156, 25)") {
                orangeToBlue();
            }
            else
            if (document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color === "rgb(25, 124, 255)") {
                blueToGreen();
            }
            else
            if (document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color === "rgb(25, 255, 41)") {
                greenToPink();
            }
            else
            if (document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color === "rgb(255, 25, 239)") {
                pinkToOrange();
            }
        }


//html
<h1 id="webTitle" onclick="changeColor()" style="color: #FF9C19;" >Webpage Title</h1>



//css
 #webTitle:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        #webTitle {
            text-shadow: 3.5px 3.5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            font-size: 100px;
            font-family: fantasy;
        }
```

Comment: So, after changing some things, explain to me why THIS doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/DITTO/dyjov9sw/

Comment: Your logic is correct but you are compareing "document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color" @which gives rgb(rrr,ggg,bbb) color value with #rrggbb

Comment: So what you are saying is that I need to convert the style.color to rgb? Or are you saying I should use hex codes instead on the "rgb(rrr, ggg, bbb)" in the comparison?

Comment: no i am saying d"ocument.getElementById("webTitle").style.color" returns a color value as a string in the form rgb(rrr,ggg,bbb)

Comment: But I'm comparing that to another rgb(rrr, ggg, bbb) to check if the color matches. They should match up, right?

Comment: i am saying "document.getElementById("webTitle").style.color" returns color in rbg(rrr,bbb,ggg) so you should compare this value color value in rbg(rrr,bbb,ggg) format instant of color values in #rrggbb formet

Comment: Look at the fiddle please. That's EXACTLY what I did.