# javascript style.display only work with css inline

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do not understand this behavior.

If I set style "display:none" inline works properly when I click on ChangeDiv1 button.

If I set style "display:none" in header tag  when I click on ChangeDiv2 button document.getElementById("conten2").style.display is empty.

If I do not set style "display:none" when I click on ChangeDiv3 button document.getElementById("conten3").style.display is empty.

How can I solve this?

```js
  function cambiar1() {
    var miElemento1 = document.getElementById("conten1").style.display;
    if (miElemento1 == "block") document.getElementById("conten1").style.display = "none";
    if (miElemento1 == "none") document.getElementById("conten1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('estadoconten1').innerHTML = 'State Div1:' + document.getElementById("conten1").style.display;
  }
 
  function cambiar2() {
    var miElemento2 = document.getElementById("conten2").style.display;
    if (miElemento2 == "block") document.getElementById("conten2").style.display = "none";
    if (miElemento2 == "none") document.getElementById("conten2").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('estadoconten2').innerHTML = 'State Div2:' + document.getElementById("conten2").style.display;
  }
 
   function cambiar3() {
    var miElemento3 = document.getElementById("conten3").style.display;
    if (miElemento3 == "block") document.getElementById("conten3").style.display = "none";
    if (miElemento3 == "none") document.getElementById("conten3").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('estadoconten3').innerHTML = 'State Div3:' + document.getElementById("conten3").style.display;
  }
```

```css
#estadoconten1 {border:solid 1px red}
#conten2 {display:none; border:solid 1px green}
#conten3 {border:solid 1px blue}
```

```html
<h2>
MODIFY "LOAD TYPE" AT JAVASCRIPT MENU AND SET "IN HEAD" OPTION
</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="cambiar1()">ChangeDiv1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="cambiar2()">ChangeDiv2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="cambiar3()">ChangeDiv3</button>
<div id='estadoconten1'></div>
<div id='estadoconten2'></div>
<div id='estadoconten3'></div>
<br>
<div id='conten1' style='display:none'>
I am Div 1
</div>
<br>
<div id='conten2'>
I am Div 2
</div>
<br>
<div id='conten3'>
I am Div 3
</div>
```

[Example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wa1b992r/9/)

Comment: The code related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Use Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to create a runnable demo like jsFiddle **on-site**.

Comment: From [MDN HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) "The HTMLElement.style property returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object that represents only the element's inline style attribute, ignoring any applied style rules."

Answer (score 0):

You check if an elememt has display: block or none. However there are many others like **initial, inline,outline ...** . thats why your js doesnt work.
Explicitly set it to your css:

```
#conten1,#conten2,#conten3{
display:block;
}
```

Or change your js

```
if(element.style.display=="none"){
//element is hidden
//display
}else{
//elememt is not hidden
//hide
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Please review the Example jsfiddle, because your answer is tried on DIV2.

DIV2 has set "display:none" in CSS and then show the current state with
    "document.getElementById('estadoconten1').innerHTML = 'State Div1:' + document.getElementById("conten1").style.display"

Comment: @D. Ortega: did you tried the js solution??

Comment: the js solution is NOT working because "element.style.display" is "" instead of "block, none, initial, inline,outline ..."

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle anything other than "none" to "none".  You can toggle "none" to "block".

```js
function cambiar(idx) {
  var el = document.getElementById("conten" + idx);
  var miElemento = el.style.display;
  if (miElemento === "none") {
    el.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    el.style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById('estadoconten' + idx).innerHTML = 'State Div' + idx + ':' + el.style.display;
}
```

```css
#estadoconten1 {
  border: solid 1px red
}
#conten2 {
  display: none;
  border: solid 1px green
}
#conten3 {
  border: solid 1px blue
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="cambiar(1)">ChangeDiv1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="cambiar(2)">ChangeDiv2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="cambiar(3)">ChangeDiv3</button>
<div id='estadoconten1'></div>
<div id='estadoconten2'></div>
<div id='estadoconten3'></div>
<br>
<div id='conten1' style='display:none'>
  I am Div 1
</div>
<br>
<div id='conten2'>
  I am Div 2
</div>
<br>
<div id='conten3'>
  I am Div 3
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

display is not part of the element unless is has specifically been set. 
see this answer.

[document.getElementById(...).style.display is blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688638/document-getelementbyid-style-display-is-blank)