# Html page not responding to first button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var vw = 0;
var vh = 0;

 function myFunction(idx, vw, vh) {
    if (document.getElementById(idx).style.display === "none") {
        document.getElementById('shade').style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('shade').style.opacity = 1;
        }, 100);
        document.getElementById(idx).style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById(idx).style.width = vw + 'px';
        }, 100);
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById(idx).style.height = vh + 'px';
        }, 100);
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById(idx).style.opacity = 1;
        }, 100);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById(idx).style.width = '0px';
        }, 100);
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById(idx).style.height = '0px';
        }, 100);
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById(idx).style.opacity = 0;
        }, 100);
        document.getElementById(idx).clientWidth = 0;
        if (document.getElementById(idx).style.opacity == 0) {
            document.getElementById(idx).style.display = "none";
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('shade').style.opacity = 0;
        }, 100);
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('shade').style.display = "none";
        }, 600);
    }
 }
```

```css
.shade {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity:0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  }
 .mdiv {
  background-color:white;
  border:4px solid blue;
  border-radius:12px;
  border-style:double;;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 18px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
  display:none;
  height:0;
  left:50%;
  opacity:0;
  padding:15px;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  top:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transition: width 1s, height 1s, opacity 1s;
  width:0;
  z-index:10;
  }
```

```html
<div id="shade" class="shade" onclick="myFunction('mdiv',0,0)" ></div>
<div id="mdiv" class="mdiv"><img src="./graphics/volunteer.webp" style="max-width:98%; width:98%;" /></div>
<button onclick="myFunction('mdiv',300,350)" >Click me</button>
```

I am trying to build my own css/javascript popup. The code works fine on the first button click and on the overlay click.

When I try to reload the popup I have to click the button twice for it to function, It seems like the javascript is not resetting the csv back to its original state.

Could anyone help please?

### Edit

Here is a CodePen link

https://codepen.io/dcsimp/pen/WNdLjwZ

Comment: Can you show us a graphic preview of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have  inline  style `display:none` for `#mdiv` . you can check that is `none` or not:

```
document.getElementById(idx).style.display === "none"
```

so i add an inline style `display:none` to `#mdiv` tag

```
<div id="mdiv" class="mdiv" style="display:none;"></div>
```

another problem is at this section

```
    if (document.getElementById(idx).style.opacity == 0) {
        document.getElementById(idx).style.display = "none";
    }
```

because when execute this code the `if` is not `true` (`opacity` not 0 yet) and style remain `block`

you can set `display:none` at the end of `else` statement and wait for transitions.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('shade').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(idx).style.display = "none";
 }, 800);
```

and finally...

```js
   var vw = 0;
     var vh = 0;
    
     function myFunction(idx, vw, vh) {
        if (document.getElementById(idx).style.display === "none") {
            document.getElementById('shade').style.display = "block";
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById('shade').style.opacity = 1;
            }, 100);
            document.getElementById(idx).style.display = "block";
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById(idx).style.width = vw + 'px';
            }, 100);
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById(idx).style.height = vh + 'px';
            }, 100);
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById(idx).style.opacity = 1;
            }, 100);
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById(idx).style.width = '0px';
            }, 100);
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById(idx).style.height = '0px';
            }, 100);
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById(idx).style.opacity = 0;
            }, 100);
            document.getElementById(idx).clientWidth = 0;
            if (document.getElementById(idx).style.opacity === '0') {
                document.getElementById(idx).style.display = "none";
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById('shade').style.opacity = 0;
            }, 100);
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById('shade').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById(idx).style.display = "none";
            }, 800);
        
        }
     }
```

```css
.shade {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity:0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  }
  .mdiv {
  background-color:white;
  border:4px solid blue;
  border-radius:12px;
  border-style:double;;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 18px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
  display:none;
  height:0;
  left:50%;
  opacity:0;
  padding:15px;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  top:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transition: width 1s, height 1s, opacity 1s;
  width:0px;
  z-index:10;
   }
```

```html
<div id="shade" class="shade" onclick="myFunction('mdiv',0,0)" ></div>
  <div id="mdiv" class="mdiv" style="display:none;"></div>
  <button onclick="myFunction('mdiv',200,250)" >Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688638/document-getelementbyid-style-display-is-blank) , Unfortunately the .style property only knows about the style properties set using that same

you're document.getElementById(idx).style.display is initially  "" that's why its not working , what you can add is an empty check