# div needs to be clicked twice to trigger event listener js

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on the .current-pet-icon div, I need to click it twice before it shows my menu. but every subsequent click after is okay. Just when I refresh / load the page the first time I need to double click. Any help wpuld be greatly appreciated!

**Javascript**

```
const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.current-pet-icon')
const openedNav = document.querySelector('.nav-popout');
const shadowNav = document.querySelector('.shadow-nav');

menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (openedNav.style.display === "none") {
    openedNav.style.display = "block";
    shadowNav.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    openedNav.style.display = "none";
    shadowNav.style.display = "none";
  }
});

shadowNav.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (openedNav.style.display = "block") {
    openedNav.style.display = "none";
    shadowNav.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="pet-icon-container">
    <img class="current-pet-icon" src="https://www.burgesspetcare.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Hamster.jpg" alt="current pet icon">
  </div>
```

Comment: `openedNav.style.display = "block"` -> `openedNav.style.display === "block"`

Comment: what are the styles of your openedNav?

Answer (score 0):

A quick `console.log(openedNav.style.display)` will help you find the issue. In the first call to the click handler, `openNav.style.disply` is actually empty (not `'none'`).

#### Why does this happen

If you access a DOM Element via `getElementById`, you'll not be able to read the computed style of that element, because it is defined inside the CSS file (I assume you are doing that).

#### How to fix it

use `getComputedStyle`. Or see the top answers to these questions if you wanna know more:

- [document.getElementById(...).style.display is blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688638/document-getelementbyid-style-display-is-blank)
- [myDiv.style.display returns blank when set in master stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748813/mydiv-style-display-returns-blank-when-set-in-master-stylesheet)

```js
menuToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (getComputedStyle(openedNav).display=== "none") {
    openedNav.style.display = "block";
    shadowNav.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    openedNav.style.display = "none";
    shadowNav.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is a CSS style assigned to hide both `.nav-popout` and `.shadow-nav` elements initially then a modified version of the original js code appears to function as expected.

```js
const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.current-pet-icon')
const openedNav = document.querySelector('.nav-popout');
const shadowNav = document.querySelector('.shadow-nav');

menuToggle.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  openedNav.style.display = openedNav.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
  shadowNav.style.display = shadowNav.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
});



shadowNav.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  if( openedNav.style.display == "block" ) {
    shadowNav.style.display = openedNav.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
.pet-icon-container img{
   width:150px;
}

.nav-popout,
.shadow-nav{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="pet-icon-container">
  <img class="current-pet-icon" src="https://www.burgesspetcare.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Hamster.jpg" alt="current pet icon" />
</div>

<div class='nav-popout'>#NAV-POPOUT#</div>
<div class='shadow-nav'>#SHADOW-NAV#</div>
```