# How do I calculate the absolute position of a relatively positioned element *without* using jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I know plenty of ways to calculate the offset or position of an element with jQuery, but I am working on a library that will be used by clients who may or may not be using jQuery and I need to keep it as small as possible.

Is there a lightweight library or an example somewhere that works the same way as the jQuery's offset() function?

Comment: You can use the [Computed Style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134471/have-problem-when-use-elements-that-added-to-an-array-with-document-getelementb/6134501#6134501) and look for the `top` and `left` property

Comment: Take a look: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/offset.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at jquery's code and see how it calculates element positions.

Keep in mind that jquery is designed to work everywhere.

Comment: I know that I can steal code from jquery, but that ties into a lot of other parts of jquery and makes it a non-trivial task to take from the file that @karim79 linked to above; I guess I just figured that someone else might have sometime needed to solve the problem in a cross-platform way that couldn't use jquery before me

Answer (score 3):

```
elem.offsetLeft
elem.offsetTop
```

These two properties tell you the position of the element `elem` relative to its `offsetParent`. The offsetParent of an element is usually a container with `position: relative`, a table, or the document itself (or a few other things I don't remember).

You can loop through the `offsetParent` chain until there are no more parents, adding the `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` together to get the position relative to the whole page.

Comment: My understanding is that this method doesn't always work on some versions of Internet Explorer; am I mistaken?

Comment: Ahh; I remembered there was an issue. This method does not take into account any borders set on various parent containers

Comment: Really? That's odd, never had that problem myself... Still, that can be fixed by getting `computedStyle(elem)['border-width']` (and for older IE: `function computedStyle(elem) {return elem.currentStyle;};`)

Comment: .. and walk up the DOM doing that.  Yeah, I think I'll end up having to just port the jQuery offset into a standalone library.  Somewhat annoying. I'm still shocked that nobody else seems to have done it.