# How to revert back to a value in css

Tags: css

I'm trying to bring up certain elements by their z-index

```
z-index:100;
```

But then I need to put them back to where they were, how do I get that value or even just set to it without actually knowing it?

Comment: where are you trying to do this? in javascript? what do you mean by "bring up"?

Comment: you will have to use javascript for that. You need to get the computed style. check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134471/using-elements-that-are-added-to-an-array-with-document-getelementbyidid/6134501#6134501)

Comment: back to auto? z-index: auto; - its the default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to bring up an element and bring it back down - you can add/remove a class to override the previous z-index - assuming you don't need to know the orignal z-index.