# Select element with certain style?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to select an element with certain style using CSS?
Like... all img that has `style="position:fixed;"`

What I mean is - selecting elements depending on their style instead of class or id.

Comment: `img[style="position:fixed;"]` @JoshC... but I doubt that's really what the OP needs.

Comment: Is this style defined in the html itself, or are you trying to do it based on other CSS rules?

Comment: with javascript yes it is possible, but that will be too much to do, going through each element and geting their [computed style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134471/using-elements-that-are-added-to-an-array-with-document-getelementbyidid/6134501#6134501) but what are you trying to accomplish really?

Comment: Show us the actual HTML and CSS.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Cool that works - assuming you use the `style` attribute.. It seems to be exactly what the OP wants.. http://jsfiddle.net/BJeXM/

Comment: @JoshC Notice though how picky you need to be: http://jsfiddle.net/BJeXM/1/

Comment: @WesleyMurch Yes, it get differences like `#f00` != `#ff0000`. It seems to be a string comparision indeed.

Comment: Here is the actual code - http://jsfiddle.net/HvZCL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd actually use that one:

```
[style~="position:fixed;"]{
  /* whatever */
}
```

See the explanation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value_contains.asp)

so it'll catch all elements that have `position:fixed;` in their style (because they may have other styles attributes as well)

But if that `position` attribute is not written in the HTML, the selector will not select them. you will have to use JQuery for that. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220834/select-all-elements-that-have-a-specific-css-using-jquery)

Comment: is it different that the other answers? I'm trying to understand the difference between style~= and style=

Comment: `=` means that the style equals exactly the value, where `~=` means that the style contains the value. see the difference in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/KCvgL/1/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T4guf/ what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you have spaces in the string. see [that](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/HvZCL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
div[style="position:fixed;"] {
    color:red;
}
```

to select all elements like this

```
<div style="position:fixed;">
</div>
```

But be careful, you have to take the statement `style="position:fixed;"` exactly that way into your selector. Even if you omit the `;` or add a blank space (`position: fixed`) it won't lead to your desired result anymore.

Comment: The semicolon makes all the difference. You need that semicolon in the markup for the selector to match.

Comment: Oh yeah, I changed that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute selector:

```
[style="position:fixed;"]{
  /* whatever */
}
```

Here's a demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvfDi

If you want to select each element with a style='position:anything', I would take a look at the w3c spec on css3 attribute selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors